# VS Code changes indentation on copy/paste

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Python. According to the PEP 8 Style Guide, both of these are acceptable -

```
my_list = [
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    ]

my_list = [
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
]
```

I prefer the former. However, if I copy and paste a block like this, VS Code changes the indentation like this -

```
my_list = [
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    ]
    my_list = [
        1, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6,
        ]
```

Is there a setting to change this behaviour?

Comment: What extensions do you currently have enabled?

Comment: Only the Python extension

Comment: Python or Python for VS Code? Like does it say anything under Extensions -> Enabled?

Comment: Extensions -> Enabled shows Python 2019.8.29288. If I hover over it, it says 'Extension is enabled locally'

Comment: When I enable that I do not get the same formatting indentation as you described in your question. v2019.3.6558 here

Comment: Are you saying that your extension is an older version? Could that make a difference?

Comment: Definitely a different version but I think it's unlikely that there are formatting changes between our versions seeing how PEP 8 style guide probably hasn't changed that much. Try and disable the extension to ensure that's whats causing it.

Comment: I opened a blank page with Ctrl+N, so it does not use the Python extension, and it does *not* change the indentation. I will try the suggestion made by aaaakshat and reply there. Thanks

Comment: I dont know if that solution is going to be the right one for you long term. I'd disable the extension and open up a new .py file then paste and save and see if it happens there.

Comment: I disabled the extension and installed Python for VS Code. It seems to be working correctly. I will monitor it for a while. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see that the problem has been raised as an issue on Git-Hub - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6886